# How to get the port of a connection in mysql

Tags: mysql

I can do:

```
select * from information_schema.processlist plist where id=connection_id();
```

To get the data from the current connection I am on, this will give me something that looks like:

```
# ID, USER, HOST, DB, COMMAND, TIME, STATE, INFO
'6558851', 'avails', '99-29.lit:55353', 'aQvails', 'Query', '0', 'executing', 'select * from information_schema.processlist plist where id=connection_id()'
```

And the port in there is `55353`. Is there a way to grab the port directly, for example something like:

```
SELECT connection_id(), user(), port_id(??)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use one of the solutions in this StackOverflow: [How do I find out my MySQL URL, host, port and username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093603/how-do-i-find-out-my-mysql-url-host-port-and-username#:%7E:text=If%20using%20MySQL%20Workbench%2C%20simply,pane%20located%20in%20the%20sidebar.&text=If%20you%20use%20phpMyAdmin%2C%20click,MySQL%20server%20is%20running%20on.)
Specifically I think this is what you're looking for: `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';`

Comment: Also `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'port';` or `SELECT variable_value FROM information_schema.SESSION_VARIABLES WHERE variable_name = 'port';`